# Inconsistent VS debugger behaviour - Aurelia project

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2017, google-chrome-devtools, aurelia

I'm using Chrome, Aurelia, and Visual Studio 2017 for my project but the debugger will not consistently hit breakpoints.

*versions are - chrome 63.0.3239.84 and VS 2017 Community Preview (2) - version 15.5.0 Preview 5*

Follow the steps below to repo.

**Setup**

- dotnet new aurelia
- npm install
- open project in Visual Studio

**Scenario 1**

1. Open boot.ts and put a breakpoint on the first line of the configure(..) method
2. Run project -> Chrome opens and chrome shows vs debugging is on.
3. App renders in chrome. -> breakpoint is not hit
4. Stop run
5. Add a second breakpoint to the first line of the configureRouter(..) method of the app.ts file
6. Run project -> breakpoint is hit

**Scenario 2**

1. Perform scenario 1 sequence to step 6
2. As soon as chrome opens, press F12 to open developer tools
3. App renders -> no breakpoints are hit. breakpoints in VS have warning symbol "The breakpoint will not currently be hit..."

**Scenario 3**

1. Perform scenario 1 sequence to step 6
2. F5 past two breakpoints. App renders
3. Refresh browser -> breakpoints are hit
4. F12 to open chrome dev tools in browser
5. Refresh browser  -> breakpoints not hit
6. F12 to close chrome dev tools in browser
7. Refresh browser -> breakpoints not hit

**Scenario 4**

1. Remove all breakpoints
2. Run project -> app renders in chrome
3. add breakpoint to boot.ts
4. Refresh browser -> breakpoint is hit

Opening the chrome debugger tools seems to disconnect the visual studio debugger. But [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322313/visual-studio-community-2017-stops-debugging-when-i-open-chrome-developer-tool) make me think it might be a project setting of some sort. I have no idea why the breakpoint in `boot.ts` fails to hit without a second in `app.ts` when the project it started. It is making debugging somewhat tedious.

1. Can anyone repo ?
2. Any idea as to a fix ?

**UPDATE**

Just found this in the debugger output of VS.

*Visual Studio does not support additional debuggers attached to a web-page when multi-client remote debugging support is enabled in Chrome. Visual Studio is disconnecting the JavaScript debugger because we detected that Chrome Dev Tools were opened for this page: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?remoteBase=https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@8f51ed0e633e109109762a3deb18a50e8c138819/&can_dock=true&hasOtherClients=true&dockSide=undocked*

So that would explain the F12 issue. But I still can resolve why a standalone boot.ts breakpoint wont hit on first run.

**UPDATE 2**

Multiple debuggers is actually possible. For how to do this see my post on the [MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5cd1aa58-d986-4d03-a10e-bf1fd62080a7/simultaneous-debugging-in-chrome?forum=vsdebug) where I hope the team will rectify the problem.

Comment: What bundling system are you using? Have you updated all nuget and npm dependencies?

Comment: Webpack. Modified all the version tags in the package.json to 'latest', but same behaviour.

Comment: @OrdinaryOrange,Have you checked “Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET(Chrome and IE)” in Debug > Options? As far as I know, the VS2017 supports this feature(Debugging JS or TS file in Google Chrome), we don't use the two debugger together: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/

Comment: Yes that option is checked. If I uncheck it then all of the breakpoint markers become hollow red, with message "breakpoint will not be hit...". So that't not it. As far as the chrome debugger is concerned you should read my MSDN post, the VS team has work to do.

Comment: @OrdinaryOrange, so it is the same issue as this one shared by you here:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5cd1aa58-d986-4d03-a10e-bf1fd62080a7/simultaneous-debugging-in-chrome?forum=vsdebug#5cd1aa58-d986-4d03-a10e-bf1fd62080a7, am I right?

Comment: Almost. Since originally posting this, I'd discovered that there are two problems at play here. One is the VS debugger detaching (as I've posted on MSDN) and the other outstanding issue is why a single breakpoint in boot.ts fails to get hit without a second in app.ts, which I don't think is related to the debugger detaching issue.

Comment: @OrdinaryOrange, Thanks for your response, since one thread for one issue. For the debugger issue, since you have submitted a feature request to the product team, if possible, you could add it as the answer, so other community members who have the same requests could find the user voice easily and vote it. Have a nice day:)